# Debuging geolocalization on real device with ionic

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

How to debug geolocalization on real device making ionic app?
I'm using `ionic cordova run android --device --livereload` command which uses IP (not localhost) and I get `Only secure origins are allowed.` error.

Is there a way to debug app on real device connected with USB ?

Code to get position:

```
odswiezGps() {
    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition({
        enableHighAccuracy: true
    }).then((resp) => {
        this.gps = resp;
        console.log(resp);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error getting location', error);
    });
}
```

Comment: You can use chrome://inspect with windows with google chrome

Comment: I have Developer Tools opened. From there I got `Only secure origins` error. Or You have something different on mind

Comment: Can please post your code?

Comment: Post edited above